# How to filter/customize search module in Prestashop 1.5?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, prestashop-1.5

I have a prestashop website and I am having the following issue.

My free prestashop search module (by default) it searches and displays results from every category at the same time :
I have the following categories near the search bar

1. All categories.
2. Food
3. Drinks
4. Deserts

I want to customize the search so when i click(and select) food , the display results both in ajax search and main query search to be only from the food category and not from Drinks or Deserts.

And I want to keep all categories search through all the categories bellow !

Might anybody give me some clues on how to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please where are you at this? If you have some code, it will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do an override of SearchController.php

There is a docu: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingacontroller

Comment: Me too I started but still don't find a comprehensive solution to this issue. Thanks for collaborating on publishing an answer on SO about this, here or in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769588/add-additional-conditions-to-the-default-search-mechanism-prestashop-1-6-0-6