# Search products in a specific category

Tags: sql, content-management-system, prestashop

I am trying to extend the default behaviour of the search mechanism provided by the default module `blocksearch` in Prestashop  1.6.0.6.

I added to the default form a `select` input returning categories.

Everything is working in both controller and view sides. The whole form is sending the correct parameter to the `SearchController`.  But, in Model, I still don't know what are the changes to apply on `Search.php` entity so that the method `find`  returns products that belong to the specified  category. 
I spent a good time trying to understand how the search mechanism in `find` works but to no avail. Can someone please point me the concerned part of code? where to add my conditions on `category_id` in SQL?

**Edit:**
Among all the sql queries in `Search::find` method, I think the following one is the concerned. In fact, I added `AND p.'id_manufacturer' ='.(int)$manufacturer_id.'` and I can see changes. But for categories, it seems more complicated, I think I need a `JOIN` somewhere. I am afraid I build things that can apparently working but are created with no respect to best practices. Please to help me I am a newbie in sql.

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, 
                pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`name`,
             MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image, il.`legend`, m.`name` manufacturer_name '.$score.', MAX(product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute`) id_product_attribute,
                DATEDIFF(
                    p.`date_add`,
                    DATE_SUB(
                        NOW(),
                        INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
                    )
                ) > 0 new
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $context->shop).'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)'.
                Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                WHERE p.`id_product` '.$product_pool.'
                                AND p.`id_manufacturer` ='.(int)$manufacturer_id.'
                GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
                '.($order_by ? 'ORDER BY  '.$alias.$order_by : '').($order_way ? ' '.$order_way : '').'
                LIMIT '.(int)(($page_number - 1) * $page_size).','.(int)$page_size;
```

**Edit numero 2 : temporary solution**

```
if($category_id!=0)  $sql=$sql.' AND p.`id_product` IN (SELECT `id_product` FROM `ps_category_product` p WHERE p.`id_category`='.(int)$category_id.'  )';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, 
            pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`name`,
         MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image, il.`legend`, m.`name` manufacturer_name '.$score.', MAX(product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute`) id_product_attribute,
            DATEDIFF(
                p.`date_add`,
                DATE_SUB(
                    NOW(),
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY
                )
            ) > 0 new
            FROM  `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`

            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
            INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
            )

            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
            '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $context->shop).'
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)'.
            Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1').'
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
            WHERE p.`id_product` '.$product_pool.'
                            AND p.`id_manufacturer` ='.(int)$manufacturer_id.' AND cp.id_lang ='.(int)$id_category.'
            GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
            '.($order_by ? 'ORDER BY  '.$alias.$order_by : '').($order_way ? ' '.$order_way : '').'
            LIMIT '.(int)(($page_number - 1) * $page_size).','.(int)$page_size;
```

where (int)$id_category is the id_category (from the select) and category_product is the table storing the relation between products and categories

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try to read it when I will have time (I am not into PS anymore). Hope it helps others. +1

Comment: i thought that the question is recent :\, hope that it helps others, and thanks for +1